# Append near tables, error message

Tags: arcgis-desktop, nearest-neighbor, append

I have 50 near tables that I want to append, so I can export them at once.

However, when I use the append tool an error comes up saying that the near tables are 'read only'. Is there anyway to make this append possible?

Comment: Can you add details about the version of ArcGIS Desktop you're using (I'm guessing it is)? Just in case there're version specific issues.

Comment: Do you have an mxd open in another window that has the same fc open that you are trying to append to, that will cause that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Target Dataset added in the project, it may cause to be read-only or if you have Target Dataset among the Input Datasets.

Open a new (empty) project (or even restart ArcMap), and make sure the Target Dataset is not among Input Datasets and run the tool.

Another posibility is that you are experiencing the issue discussed [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/63440).

Comment: Thanks! I started a new project and included only the files I wanted to append. Seems to be working!